# Alamofire Promise make generic request method

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, alamofire

I am trying to implement a generic method which is used to get data from API call.

Here is My code.

```
 class Http {
       class func asyncGetRequest()->Promise<List> {
        return Promise {
            resolve in
            Alamofire.request(GET_PROFFESSIONAL).responseData().done { response in
                guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(List.self, from: response.data) else {
                    let error = MyError(message: "Error: Couldn't decode")
                    resolve.reject(error)
                    return
                }
                    resolve.fulfill(blog as List)
                }.ensure {

                }.catch { error in
                    resolve.reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make a generic method for all request. In my code, I made promise type **List**
and `JSONDecoder().decode(List.self)`, Here I would like to make **List** type dynamic. How can we do that? I would like to reuse  **asyncGetRequest** method for all the API calls. I want to pass request URL (**GET_PROFFESSIONAL**) and  **List** class type as dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Generics and write something like this:

```
class Http {
    class func asyncGetRequest<ListType: Decodable>() -> Promise<ListType> {
        return Promise { resolve in
            Alamofire.request(GET_PROFFESSIONAL).responseData().done { response in
                guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ListType.self, from: response.data) else {
                    let error = MyError(message: "Error: Couldn't decode")
                    resolve.reject(error)
                    return
                }
                    resolve.fulfill(blog as ListType)
                }.ensure {

                }.catch { error in
                    resolve.reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EvilCoder No problem! You can vote for my answer :)

Comment: When using above method getting nill data.         'let listData: Promise<List> = self.asyncGetRequest()
        print(listData.value)'

Comment: How can access the list data from that promise valie

Comment: let list = self.asyncGetRequest().value?.then { data -> Void in
            return data
        }
// error Generic parameter 'ListType' could not be inferred

Comment: @EvilCoder Can you try specify your list Type? I mean like this: `let list: YourListType = self.asyncGetRequest().value?.then { data -> Void in return data }`

Comment: sorry to disturb you, I'm new to promises just started today. I would like to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

- Alamofire (5.2.2)
- PromiseKit (6.13.1)

```swift
struct Network {
  static func get<Mode: Codable>(url: String) -> Promise<Mode> {
    return Promise { seal in
      AF.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .response { response in
          
          if let error = response.error {
            seal.reject(error)
            return
          }
          
          guard let data = response.data else { return }
          
          do {
            let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Mode.self, from: data)
            seal.resolve(items, nil)
          } catch {
            seal.reject(error)
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```